# Function to allow show and hide on menu for different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

Bit new to JS /jQuery so any help greatly appreciated...

Basically I'm building a responsive header and want to enable `onclick` functions to the items for when browsing on tablet/mobile resolutions only.

I have been trying work out and write a function that does the following:

- If the page is loaded, and is 768px or less wide, allow buttons to reveal corresponding box on click, and toggle.
- If the page is resized, and ends up being 768px or less wide, allow buttons to reveal corresponding box on click, and toggle.
- When second button is clicked, reset the boxes to hide any previously revealed box (i.e. only show one of the boxes at a time)
- When the page is resized, reset the boxes to hide any previously revealed box

Whilst what I have written works, I get inconsistent behaviour when resizing. Sometimes it does the right thing, sometimes it allows the behaviour for desktop size window but not for the intended <768px and vice versa.

I am sure I am just making basic mistakes?

I made a jfiddle as that seems to be preference on this forum from what I have seen? http://jsfiddle.net/jezzurp/gT6NQ/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>On Click Show Hide Test V3</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<style type="text/css">


/* Mobile */
@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) and (min-width:1px)
{
body{background-color:#00FFEA;}
}



div.trigger, div.display {margin:10px;padding:10px;}
div.display {display:none;}
div.display.show {display:block;}


div.trigger1 {background-color:#000000;color:#FD0004;}
div.trigger2 {background-color:#000000;color:#FFEF00;}
div.trigger3 {background-color:#000000;color:#39FF00}
div.trigger4 {background-color:#000000;color:#00C8FF;}

div.display1 {background-color:#FD0004;color:#000000;}
div.display2 {background-color:#FFEF00;color:#000000;}
div.display3 {background-color:#39FF00;color:#000000;}
div.display4 {background-color:#00C8FF;color:#000000;}
</style>
 
<script>
function menuInteraction() {
    
$(".display1.display").removeClass("show");
$(".display2.display").removeClass("show");
$(".display3.display").removeClass("show");
$(".display4.display").removeClass("show");

    var width = $(window).width(); 
    if ((width < 769)) {    

 $(".trigger1.trigger").click(function(){
  $(".display1.display").toggleClass("show");
  $(".display2.display").removeClass("show");
  $(".display3.display").removeClass("show");
  $(".display4.display").removeClass("show");
 });

 $(".trigger2.trigger").click(function(){
  $(".display2.display").toggleClass("show");
  $(".display1.display").removeClass("show");
  $(".display3.display").removeClass("show");
  $(".display4.display").removeClass("show");
 });
    
        
 $(".trigger3.trigger").click(function(){
  $(".display3.display").toggleClass("show");
  $(".display1.display").removeClass("show");
  $(".display2.display").removeClass("show");
  $(".display4.display").removeClass("show");
 });

 $(".trigger4.trigger").click(function(){
  $(".display4.display").toggleClass("show");
  $(".display1.display").removeClass("show");
  $(".display2.display").removeClass("show");
  $(".display3.display").removeClass("show");
 });

    }

}

$(document).ready(menuInteraction);
$(window).resize(menuInteraction);


</script>



</head>

<body>

<div class="trigger1 trigger">trigger 1</div>
<div class="trigger2 trigger">trigger 2</div>
<div class="trigger3 trigger">trigger 3</div>
<div class="trigger4 trigger">trigger 4</div>

<br/>

<div class="display1 display">display 1</div>
<div class="display2 display">display 2</div>
<div class="display3 display">display 3</div>
<div class="display4 display">display 4</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I took a look at your issue and I can't reproduce your inconsistencies - some more info about when it does/does not work as well as in which browsers/versions would help. To track the inconsistencies and figure out a root cause of them try using `$(window).resize(function(){alert('resize fired');});` and you can monitor when the resize event does and does not fire - then you can track down the cause.

Comment: I do get the inconsistency with Chrome 27 (Chromium on Ubuntu).

Comment: JRulle - thanks for that I will use that next time for sure. I was actually getting inconsitency in FF, Chrome and I think Safari too hence confusion.

Comment: It would basically just sometimes work as expected, I would play around with it keep resizing etc and then eventually it would stop working or even revert to opposite of desired (triggers working for larger resolutions rather than the small ones).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when the width becomes again greater than 768, you don't remove the event handlers, so they still act. Actually, I don't understand why it is inconsistent, it should consistently not work...

Anyway, removing the handlers when the width is greater than 768 fixes the problem:

```
<script>
function menuInteraction() {

    $(".display1.display").removeClass("show");
    $(".display2.display").removeClass("show");
    $(".display3.display").removeClass("show");
    $(".display4.display").removeClass("show");

    var width = $(window).width(); 
    if (width < 769) {  

        $(".trigger1.trigger").click(function(){
             $(".display1.display").toggleClass("show");
             $(".display2.display").removeClass("show");
             $(".display3.display").removeClass("show");
             $(".display4.display").removeClass("show");
        });

        $(".trigger2.trigger").click(function(){
            $(".display2.display").toggleClass("show");
            $(".display1.display").removeClass("show");
            $(".display3.display").removeClass("show");
            $(".display4.display").removeClass("show");
        });


        $(".trigger3.trigger").click(function(){
          $(".display3.display").toggleClass("show");
          $(".display1.display").removeClass("show");
          $(".display2.display").removeClass("show");
          $(".display4.display").removeClass("show");
        });

        $(".trigger4.trigger").click(function(){
            $(".display4.display").toggleClass("show");
            $(".display1.display").removeClass("show");
            $(".display2.display").removeClass("show");
            $(".display3.display").removeClass("show");
        });

    } else {

        $(".trigger1.trigger").off("click");
        $(".trigger2.trigger").off("click");
        $(".trigger3.trigger").off("click");
        $(".trigger4.trigger").off("click");

    }

}

$(document).ready(menuInteraction);
$(window).resize(menuInteraction);

</script>
```

Comment: Ok cool thanks for that. I actually did it slightly differently in the end but may throw this in and have a play with it. Appreciate the reply!

Comment: And yeah the inconsistency was just baffling me!